# Software development terminology is off-topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

A question from yesterday about what to call different focuses in development was closed as off-topic - but I can't see where in the FAQ this would fall foul.

[Terms for different types of development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142876/terms-for-different-types-of-development)

To quote the FAQ:

> Programmers — Stack Exchange is a site for professional programmers who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software development.

If one of the closing users had deigned to comment on the question, maybe I'd better understand how this question is off-topic.

Comment: Just a clarification: The question was closed by three regular users and a moderator.

Comment: Perhaps try and edit your question to remove all references to the `resume` and flag it to be reopened... I think it's a decent programmer-specific question and wouldn't have closed it personally. The basis of the question is what to call a type of development, not help building a resume.

Comment: @Rachel - It isn't my question, I just think it's a good one. Just because he wants to know what to put on his resume, it still works as a general question because the terminology wouldn't be different in another context, would it?

Comment: @HorusKol I think users are just seeing the word `resume` and immediately thinking it's a question about career advice and voting to close. I didn't realize it wasn't your question, so I edited it to remove all references to resumes and flagged it for a moderator to reopen.

Comment: @Rachel "resume help" is also off topic, regardless of career advise, check the FAQ. But I tend to agree that this isn't really a resume help question.

Answer (score 5):

The [version of the question that has been closed](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/142876/2) is tagged **resume** and starts with

> I'm working on a **resume**

which puts it into off-topic per [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq):

> ...is **not about**...
>
> - résumé help<sup>1</sup>
>
> ...
> <sup>1</sup> *For answers to common programming career advice questions, please see "[Don’t Call Yourself A Programmer, And Other Career Advice](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2011/10/28/dont-call-yourself-a-programmer/)" by Patrick McKenzie.*

---

As for software development [terminology](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology), it is typically considered on-topic.

---

### update

After major edit done in rev 3, question has been reopened (reference: [post timeline](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/142876/timeline)).

> I also revoked question downvote thanks to edit mentioned above.

Comment: so the `resume` tag is kind of a bobby trap for people not reading the faq? Is it going to be removed?

Comment: @Simon Thats a good point.  The FAQ explicitly states that resume help is off topic, yet it still exists as a tag.  Yannis, perhaps another STCI initiative is in the works?

Comment: @Simon well this tag is slippery, but looking at [questions currently tagged 'resume'](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume) I wouldn't call it a "trap": 90 open vs 40 closed.

Comment: @gnat consider this question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/132252/should-i-include-not-yet-released-projects-on-my-resume-cv It isn't closed but is about resume help. So your statistic is slightly wrong. At least there could be a tag wiki.

Comment: @Simon where exactly is my statistic wrong? you can re-check it yourself: URL for open resume questions is `http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=[resume]+closed%3A0` (shows 90 to me now) and for closed ones is `http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=[resume]+closed%3A1` (shows 40 now)

Comment: @gnat the statistic may be wrong because some open questions fall in the `resume help` category and therefore should be closed according to the faq. The there might be more off topic question with the `resume` tag than your statistic is actually showing. In order to assess the tag, one should have to check each question and see if it is working well enough.

Comment: @Simon I see - that makes sense

Comment: That's pretty tenuous, especially as so many other resume tagged questions remain open - if the word 'resume' was replaced with 'essay', what would magically make it better? While the context (and motivation) is to create a better resume, this is not the primary aspect of the question.

Comment: @HorusKol well if you believe _this is not the primary aspect of the question_ - the [road is open, go ahead](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/491/31260 "'closed question... can be improved, discussed, and voted to re-open'"). Request it to be reopened (edit it if you feel the need to cleanup) and let the community vote to re-open.